# Passing custom objects between activities?

Tags: java, android

How do I pass custom objects between activites in android? I'm aware of bundles but I can't seem to see any functionality for this in them. Could anyone show me a nice example of this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should implement [Parcelable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141166/5599807).

Link to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Comment: Why is it not possible to send objects in bundle? I mean, why is Android not supporting it? All the activities run in same process so isn't it easy to support it?

Comment: @Enigma I think I get your question. If you mean "pass reference to the object" in bundle, then it is a bad idea, because Activity which created the object can be destroyed due to low memory and the object will be lost.

Comment: if there is a reference to an object, it will not get destroyed! i think there should be something more technical than Garbage Collection stuff, about this!

Comment: @EhsanMirsaeedi if your reference is preventing enclosing object from being garbage collected, then you have a memory leak.

Comment: @Igor Filippov Link is death

Comment: @SvenB I guess Android developer documentation explains it good enough.

Comment: The first link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

Using Parcelable interface you can pass custom java object into the intent.

1) implement the Parcelable interface to your class like:

```
class Employee implements Parcelable
{
}
```

2) Pass the Parcelable object into the intent like:

```
Employee mEmployee =new Employee();
Intent mIntent = new Intent(mContect,Abc.class);
mIntent.putExtra("employee", mEmployee);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

3) Get the data into the new [Abc] Activity like:

```
Intent mIntent  = getIntent();
Employee mEmployee  = (Employee )mIntent.getParcelableExtra("employee");
```

Answer (score 1):

a `Parcel` MIGHT solve your problem.

think of a `Parcel` as an "array" (metaphorical) of primitive types (long, String, Double, int, etc).  **if your custom class** is composed of **primitive types ONLY**, then change your class declaration including `implements Parcelable`.

you can pass a parcelable object thru an intent with no difficulty whatsoever (just like you would send a primitive-typed object).  in this case i have a **parcelable custom class** called **FarmData** (composed of longs, strings and doubles) which i pass from one activity to another via intent.

```
    FarmData farmData = new FarmData();
// code that populates farmData - etc etc etc
    Intent intent00 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.yourpackage.yourclass.class);
    intent00.putExtra("farmData",farmData);
    startActivity(intent00);
```

but retrieving it may be tricky.  the activity that receives the intent will check if a bundle of extras was send along with the intent.

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    FarmData farmData = new FarmData();
    Intent intentIncoming = getIntent();
    if(extras != null) {
        farmData = (FarmData) intentIncoming.getParcelableExtra("farmData");// OK
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an object PasswordState that implements Serializable throughout the object tree, you can pass this object to anther activity as in:

```
private void launchManagePassword() {
    Intent i= new Intent(this, ManagePassword.class); // no param constructor
    PasswordState outState= new PasswordState(lengthKey,timeExpire,isValidKey,timeoutType,"",model.getIsHashPassword());
    Bundle b= new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable("jalcomputing.confusetext.PasswordState", outState);
    i.putExtras(b);
    startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_MANAGE_PASSWORD); // used for callback
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to pass an object between activities or make a object common for all applicattion, is create a class extending Application.

Here is a example:

```
public class DadosComuns extends Application{

    private String nomeUsuario="";

    public String getNomeUsuario() {
        return nomeUsuario;
    }

    public void setNomeUsuario(String str) {
        nomeUsuario = str;
    }
}
```

In all your others activities, you just need instantiate one object "DadosComuns", declarating as a Global Variable.

```
private DadosComuns dadosComuns;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //dados comuns
    dadosComuns = ((DadosComuns)getApplicationContext());

    dadosComuns.setNomeUsuario("userNameTest"); }
```

All others activities that you instantiate  **dadosComuns = ((DadosComuns)getApplicationContext());** you can acess **getNomeUsuario() == "userNameTest"**

In your **AndroidManifest.xml** you need to have

```
<application
        android:name=".DadosComuns"
```