# Sendind an Extra with my own kind of data

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to pass an extra data to an activity, but I don't know how since my data is a variable from a specific class of mine. I have something like:

```
MyClass variable=new MyClass();
Intent intent= new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("variableName", variable);
```

I know the error in code is obvious, but I want to know how can I send data from a class of mine.

Comment: http://androidhub.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/android-intents-for-passing-data-between-activities-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

Please looking into `Parcelable` 
[How can I make my custom objects Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/example-of-implementing-parcelable)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Answer (score 0):

You will have to serialize the data and then pass. Android doesn't support passing custom objects as extras. Look at this answer here. [Passing custom objects between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621132/passing-custom-objects-between-activities)