# Which bundle should be used to pass an object

Tags: android, bundle, start-activity

I would like to pass an object from an activity to a fragment. I know how to pass the data but do not know which type of `bundle` i should use?

**UPdate**

In  other words, I have an object of type `mqttAndroidClient` and that object i want to pass from my activity to a fragment through a `bundle`. Which bundle type I should use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Serializable object and pass to bundle.putSerializable(key, value)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122149/how-to-create-serializable-object-and-pass-to-bundle-putserializablekey-value)

Answer (score 0):

you should use something like this :

make your custom class that contains your desired data to be passed and `extend` from `Serializable` or `Parcelable` and put your object as extra to your `Bundle` object and set `Bundle` as an argument to your `Fragment`.

in your `Activity`

```
...
Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("data", "yourData");
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
...
```

in your `Fragment`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String data = getArguments().getString("data");    
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i know how to pass the data, but i do not know which type of bundles i should use to pass an object.

Answer (score 0):

For relatively simple object data types, you shouldn't need a bundle at all. When you override onCreate() in the fragment that uses the argument, simply add a line of code that fetches the data from the intent.

For example, if you're passing an integer, the line would be:

```
intvar = (int)getActivity().getIntent().getInt(SOME_IDENTIFIER);
```

where SOME_IDENTIFIER is a constant that's common to both the activity and the fragment. (It would look something like "com.yourpackage.yourapp.some_identifier."

Comment: If your class uses only primitive data types, you can use a Parcel in place of a bundle. See the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621132/passing-custom-objects-between-activities