# How to create Serializable object and pass to bundle.putSerializable(key, value)

Tags: java, android, serialization, bundle

I have an activity which has an object of type `mqttQndroidClient`. this object i would like to pass it to another activity. To achieve this i read about how to solve such issue and the soltion i found was to create a class that implements `serializable` as shown below, and i did the following:

```
client = new mqttAndroidClient(..,...,..,..,);
Intent i = new Intent(act_1.this, act_2.class)
clientObject = clientObj = new (CLIENT_OBJ_KEY, client);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable(CLIENT_OBJ_KEY, clientOb.getObjValue());
```

But eclipse underscore the `b.putSerializable(CLIENT_OBJ_KEY, clientObjValue());` with red, it seems i did not cretae a `serializable` object correctly.

and the `clientObject` class that implements `serializable`, looks as below:

```
public class ClientObject implements Serializable {

    private String objectKey;
    private MqttAndroidClient objectValue;

    public ClientObject(String objectKey, MqttAndroidClient objectValue) {

        this.objectKey = objectKey;
        this.objectValue = objectValue;
    }

    public void setObjKey(String objectKey) {

        this.objectKey = objectKey;
    }

    public String getObjKey() {

        return this.objectKey;
    }

    public void setObjValue(MqttAndroidClient objValue) {

        this.objectValue = objValue;
    }

    public MqttAndroidClient getObjValue() {

        return this.objectValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because mqqtAndroidClient itself is not serializable. clientObjectValue() returns an object of type mqqtAndroidClient, and that's not serializable.

Comment: actually you have a serializable object. just pass the object of the class that implements serializable to the bundle value.

Comment: @LetsAmrIt And because that class has non-Serializable members, the thin red line will become an exception at runtime.

Comment: @EJP but i think if he passed only the serializable object to the bundle value it should work. what do u think?

Answer (score 6):

I see many problems in your solution. The biggest one is: you can not encapsulate a not serializable object inside a serializable one and hope that thing will work. To be serializable every single field must be serializable, please read the manual.

What problem are you addressing here?

1. Is it expensive to create a client for every activity (in terms of time/memory)?
2. Do you not want to reconfigure the client every time?
3. Do you want a single instance around your application?

My opinion about the first case is that is not to expensive to create a client when you need one (one per activity I suppose), by reading the [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/android-javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/android/service/MqttAndroidClient.html) about MqttAndroidClient I understand that the client is using a long running [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). This service is responsible for the client/server communications, so, I assume, the client is a very tiny wrapper to simplify service/activity communications. This imply you can create as many client as you want.

This leads us to the second point: you don't want to reconfigure the client every time.
The solution is to create a factory. Basically something like this:

```
public final class MqttClientFactory {
  public static MqttAndroidClient createClientInstance(Context context, ...) {
    MqttAndroidClient client = new MqttAndroidClient(context, ....);
    // Configure your client here
    return client;
  }
}
```

Now you can create a configured instance your [Activity.onCreate(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ...
  mMqttClient = MqttClientFactory.createClientInstance(this, ...);
  ...
}
```

If you want a single instance of you client for the entire app, there are many solutions, that generally involve the use of a [singleton](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html). I personally prefer to avoid singletons, so I suggest to override the Application class with your own, create an instance of your client there and get the reference to it from your activity.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  private MqttAndroidClient mClient;

  public void onCreate () {
    super.onCreate();

    mClient = new MqttAndroidClient(this, ...);

    ...
  }

  public final MqttAndroidClient getClient() {
    return mClient;
  }
}
```

You can now use [Context.getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) or [Acticity.getAppliaction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29) to get a reference to your custom Application. I.E.:

```
MqttAndroidClient sharedClient = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getClient();
```

You need to add your custom application to the manifest, please see the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm)

Comment: thank you for the answer. actually i do not want to maintain one object along the app. the user can create many clients as he wants.after reading your code, i am still almost in the same problem, how can i pass the client object from one activity to another?"sorry for the lack of understanding"

Comment: Hi, my point was that you have first to think if you really need to pass the same instance between the activities. If so, use a singleton or share the reference via your custom application. Take this as an advice: have the urge to share complex object between activities is symptom of a bad design.

Comment: trully appreciate such advice. but the situation is that, I have an activity the has a button"connect", when pressed a 1-client should be connected to the broker with some options (clientID,Server URI, and,,etc) 2-another activity starts that hosts two fragments (publish and subscribe) and in each of (pub and sub) fragments the same client with the same ID and options should be used for publishing and subscribing. If I passed the connection options to both fragments using bundle, this means i need to create a new client and i do not want to do so. please guide and advise

Answer (score 0):

Does the method clientObjValue() return an object ClientObject?
Is the class MqttAndroidClient also serializable?

Comment: it is "b.putSerializable(CLIENT_OBJ_KEY, clientOb.getObjValue());"