# Passing arbitrary object in Android Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I wish to pass an arbitary object via an Android intent, I have the following code:

In the activity I wish to send an intent from:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(containerListActivity, com.uk.jacob.containerdroid.activities.ContainerDetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("container", containers.get(i));
containerListActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

The activity I wish to recieve an intent:

```
System.out.println(getIntent().getExtras("container"));
```

I seem to get the error "cannot resolve method putExtra.

`containers` is essentially a Jackson JSON mapped POJO.

Comment: check this post [pass custom objects between activites in android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33073711/2032561)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing custom objects between activities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621132/passing-custom-objects-between-activities)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't put an arbitrary object in the Intent.  It needs to be `Parcelable` or `Serializable`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

You can do it a few ways:

1. Have your custom class implement `Serializable`.  This is quick to code, but may not be performant.
2. Have your custom class implement `Parcelable`.  This could be a bit of work.
3. Convert your `container` to a string using Jackson, then convert it back after using `getStringExtra`.

Comment: in android It should be Parcelable

Answer (score 1):

Serialize your JSON to a string and then push it to the intent. In the receiving activity try `getStringExtra()` to extract it from the intent object.

Comment: that fairly simple answer